# latex reference punctuation before comma

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using the IEEE style ref.

```
@article{Bessel,
    title={Handbook of Mathematical Functions},
    author={Abramowitz, M and Stegun, I A },
    journal={Engineering Dielectrics},
    volume={3},
    year={{National Bureau of Standards, Washington DC,1965}},
}
```

and this produces

[image]

However, i just want to slightly change that the comma is after the punctuation ans shown in the second pic.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add a short compilable code showing how you build the bibliography ...

Comment: Off-topic: It's not exactly optimal to place information about the publisher and address inside the `year` field. For that matter, are you sure that `@article` is the correct entry type for this publication? I would guess that `@book` is much more appropriate.

Comment: Please tell us how you produce this bibliography. The answer will depend on the bibliography package you use (you tagged this with `biblatex`, but for all we know you could also be using `natbib`, `cite`, ... if you are using an IEEE class, you are very probably not using `biblatex`). Also tell us the exact style you use. If you are using `biblatex` we also need to know whether you load `csquotes` and your document language (`babel`/`polyglossia`). All in all, that is best shown in an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Any news here? I'm going to vote to close this question as unclear what you are asking if it is not updated with more details and an MWE in due time. There are too many possible ways that could have produced this output and each requires a different solution.

Comment: I voted to close as unclear what you are asking since it is not clear how the output shown in the picture was produced.